# How to redirect user on successful ajax call? Otherwise display error message in form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, redirect

**Updated:**
Thanks for reading - My login form calls on login.php to check whether the user has entered a registered email address or not. If the address is registered, it echoes back "redirect", if it is not registered, it echoes "Email not registered". My current code only redirects to mydomain.com/#   since the form action is set to #, because I'm using the ajax to submit the form.

**How do I:**

Redirect the user to page *private.php* if the php has echoed "redirect" - otherwise how do I display "Email  not registered" *within the form*, if it echoes "Email not registered"? My login form contains a div to display the error if necessary.

**ajax:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#loginform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('login/login.php', {email: $('#email').val(), loginsubmit: 'yes'}, function(data)
    {
    if (data === "redirect") 
{ 
window.location = "http://www.gathercat.com/login/private.php"; 
} 

else {  
 $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100');
        $('#email').val(''); 
    }
, 'text');
    return false;
    }
});
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
...
    if($login_ok) 
            { 
               echo 'redirect';
            } 
            else 
            { 
                echo 'That email address is not registered';            
            } 
...
```

**login form:**

```
...
 <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" class="login" action="#">
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="My Email" required/>
     <div id="formResponse" style="display: none;"></div>
     <button type="submit" name="loginsubmit" class="loginbutton">Login</button>
...
```

**Full PHP**

```
<?php
$emailaddress = $_POST["email"];
?>
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // This query retrieves the user's information from the database using 
        // their email. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                email 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $emailaddress
        );   
        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query against the database 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {    
            die("Failed to run query"); 
        } 
        // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
        // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
        // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
        $login_ok = false; 

        // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the email
        // they entered is not registered. 

         $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
         if($row) { 
         $login_ok = true; 
         }  
        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if($login_ok) 
        { 

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
            // the user's details. 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
           echo 'redirect';
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            echo 'That email address is not registered';            
        } 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: You already have `window.location` on your success event. What is the problem in it ?

Comment: if (data === "redirect")

Comment: @ Sulthan, like I said, it does *not* redirect to the window.location URL (private.php) on submission. Instead it's redirecting me to login.php and simply displaying the PHP echo text "redirect".  Meaning that the PHP is recognizing the email address is registered, but my script is not redirecting me to the correct page.

Comment: @paddyfields, I've updated my question based on what you wrote. Can you please take a look. Thank you

Comment: @Nova, review your JavaScript code, the braces are not balanced correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the code for you as it likes like you had quite a few problems.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login/login.php",
                dataType:"text",
                data: { email: $('#email').val(), loginsubmit: 'yes' },
                success:function(response){

                    if(response == "redirect"){
                        window.location.replace("http://www.gathercat.com/login/private.php"); 
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#formResponse").html(response).fadeIn('100');
                        $('#email').val('');   
                    }
                }
            })
    });
});
```

This is untested but please let me know if you have any questions about how it works.

Comment: Ok we've made progress! Your code now produces the error within the form. But it will *not* redirect the user if the email address is correct. Try it yourself here: http://www.gathercat.com   and click "Login" in the top-right. You can use email "extra.stuff@mail.com" to check. That email *is* registered and should be redirected. Thank you paddy!

Comment: Hi, I've updated the my answer, please see if it works.

Comment: Hey, no change unfortunately.. so bizarre!!

Comment: Can you please put alert(response); under window.location and see what the alert says

Comment: I've added it, but when I submit a registered email, no alert is shown. Only the error message is displayed on the form "Email address is not registered".

Comment: On your php file, have you checked that  $login_ok is actually true when you enter the registered email address? You can test this easily by changing echo 'That email address is not registered';  to echo $login_ok

Comment: I've just included the full PHP code at the bottom of my question. I also replaced echo 'That email address is not registered';  with echo $login_ok; and when I try to submit a registered email it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even incorrectly display the "Email address not registered" anymore..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73530/discussion-between-paddyfields-and-nova).

Comment: Sorry I got dragged away! Looks like you've fixed the problem though?

Answer (score 1):

`if ( formResponse === "redirect" ) ...`

what is `formResponse` variable?

it should be `data`

`if ( data == "redirect" ) ...`

UPDATE:
may be this will help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loginform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('login/login.php', {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            loginsubmit: 'yes'
        }, function (data) {
            if (data === "redirect") {
                window.location = "http://www.gathercat.com/login/private.php";
            } else {
                $("#formResponse").html(data).fadeIn('100');
                $('#email').val('');
            }}, 'text');

            // this does not matter
            return false;
        }

        // add line below
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question based on what you wrote. Can you please take a look. Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try it and post the result. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Lee, but it still simply redirects me to mydomain.com/#.   You can try for yourself... click the "Login" button at the top-right of the following site, and you can use email "extra.stuff@mail.com" to test.    http://www.gathercat.com

Comment: Well yes, looks the problem is error from the code writing itself. Try to use firebug or web inspector to guide you to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it!

I changed my ajax to:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login/login.php",
                dataType:"text",
                data: {email: $('#emailaddy').val(), loginsubmit: 'yes'},
                success:function(result){

                    if(result === "redirect"){
                     //  window.location.replace("login/private.php"); 
                      window.location.replace("http://www.gathercat.com/login/private.php");
                        //alert(result);
                    }
                    else{

                        $("#formResponse").html(result).fadeIn('100');
                        $('#emailaddy').val('');   
                    }
                                     }
            })
    });
});
</script>
```

and removed some commented-out HTML within the bottom of my php file which was disrupting the "result" variable's content. Everything runs perfectly now. I added this answer so people could see the full code easily, but I'm giving massive credit to paddyfields for their help, thank you again. You too Lee, appreciate the support. Take care